# How do you only select the second class an element has in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

I am in need of a way to select only the second class on an element that has 2 classes so that I can pass it through an URL to use later. I have created a function that gets both classes but I only need `class2`. Is their a way to stripe the first class off and have only the second remain. Or is their a way to select only the second class.

I did not find any questions relating to this problem using just vanilla javascript.

```
<div class="class1 class2></div>
<script>

function get2ndClass(element) {

   var secondClass = element.class;
   return secondClass;

}
```

Comment: Even though at least one of the 5 answers below should show you how to do this, I think it's a bad idea. Generally, the *order* of classes in an HTML element has no meaning. If you want to use a class as a meaningful parameter, you should use a `data-` attribute. (I.e., you're using it in the URL)

Comment: 1) The order of classes is not guaranteed. So even if your HTML says `class="class1 class2 class3"`, `element.classList` could return them in a different order.
2) The `class` is NOT for storing data.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `classList` array property to first of all check whether there are at least 2 classes, then return the 2nd item in the array.

```
function get2ndClass(element) {
   return (element && element.classList.length>1) ? element.classList[1] : null;
}
```

If you're supporting older browsers which don't support `classList` then you'll need an additional line:

```
function get2ndClass(element) {
   var classList = (element) ? element.className.split(" ") : null;
   return (classList && element.classList.length>1) ? element.classList[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: `classList.item(index)` returns `undefined` if there is no element and not `null`

Answer (score 0):

use split

```js
console.log("class1 class2".split(" ").pop());
```

Comment: This would not work if the element had more then 2 classes.

Comment: @matt `select only the second class on an element that has 2 classes` read question before downvote

Comment: @Mahi, whatever your requirements are, *never* write for 2. Always write for 0, 1 or N.

Comment: @Mahi I'm not trying to be pedantic here; but 'an element that has 2 classes' does not mean that it _only_ has 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classList` to get the classes assigned to an element

```
return element.classList.length > 1 ? element.classList[1] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `classList` support, just split the element `class` attributes:

```js
function get2ndClass(elt) {
   return elt.getAttribute('class').split(' ')[1] || null;
}
console.log(get2ndClass(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]))
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `classList`

```js
function get2ndClass(element) {
  return element.classList[1] || false;
}

var $div = document.querySelector('div')
var secondClass = get2ndClass($div);

console.log(secondClass);
```

```html
<div class="firstClass secondClass"></div>
```